# Can't figure out what's wrong with my syntax in python 3 (using jupyter notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, syntax, jupyter

**In[35]**  If 10=5*2:
print("Hooray!")

```
   Input In [35]
If 10=5*2:[enter image description here][1]
   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have used "Indent" before typing " print("Hooray!") "
and made sure to place a colon after the if statement.
Let me know if I missed anything.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGJAB.png

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here, firstly python is a case-sensitive language, and `If` and `if` are not the same thing, the `if` keyword is the correct usage here. Furthermore, `=` is used for assignment, and `==` is used for comparison, since you are comparing between `10` and `5 * 2` you should be using `==` and NOT `=`

Correct usage:

```py
if 10 == 2 * 5:
    print("Hooray!")
```

Which results in:

```
Hooray!
```